# Total probability marginal of a composite function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, information-theory

I have the following expression:
$$\int\int p(z|x)\cdot log\left(p(z)\right)dzdx$$
In order to compare it to another expression that is also integrated over another RV y, I would like to marginalize it over y by using total probability.
However, I'm not sure if it suffices to add the new conditioning on the non log term:
$$\int\int\int p(z,y|x)\cdot log\left(p(z)\right)dzdxdy$$
Both probabalistic terms:
$$\int\int\int p(z,y|x)\cdot log\left(p(z|y)\right)dzdxdy$$
Or do I need to use integration by parts?

Thanks! :)

Comment: $\int p(z,y\mid x)\log p(z)\,dy = \log p(z) p(z\mid x)$